# linaro cross compiling with .deb dependency

Tags: package-management, arm, cross-compilation

I can't find the answers so I am asking here.

I use Linaro 64bit ARM cross compiler to compile my code on a local Ubuntu 14.04 64bit Linux on Intel (`gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++`).

My code requires to use `libsensor4` and `libsensor4-dev` with linker option `-lsensors`. I have no problem compiling my code using the 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 host Linux on Intel. But every time I compile my code using the 64bit ARM cross compiler it has errors:

```
cannot find -lsensors
```

and

```
sensors/sensors.h: no such file or directory.
```

The `-lsensors` is from `libsensors4.deb` and the `sensors.h` is from `libsensors4-dev`. so how can I get those two packages into the Linaro cross compiler?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get `aarch64` packages into the build system is to enable it as a foreign architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture aarch64
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can remove `libsensors4-dev` for your build architecture and install it for the host architecture `aarch64`:

```
sudo apt-get install libsensors4-dev- libsensors4-dev:aarch64+
```

It's necessary to remove the build architecture package because it can't coexist with a package of the same name for a different architecture. The dependency `libsensors4:aarch64` however can coexist with `libsensors4`<sup>1</sup>. This means that you can keep running programs on the build system that are dynamically linked against `libsensors4` but you can't use `libsensors4-dev` to link *new* build architecture programs against it.

I don't know how you configured and installed the cross-compiler but GCC usually picks up the canonical locations for header files (`/usr/include`) and library files (`/usr/lib/<architecture>-<system-type>`) which is exactly to where DPKG extracts them from `libsensors4-dev` (any architecture). If that's not the case you can tell GCC/G++ to add include file directories with `-I<PATH>` and library directories with `-L<PATH>`. Furthermore you can list current include directories with `gcc -xc++ -E -v /dev/null` and current library directories with gcc `gcc -print-search-dirs`.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can check if a package can coexist with its “sibling” of a different architecture if you look at `Multi-Arch` field in the package control information. “same” means it can coexist. Use `dpkg-query -s <PACKAGE>`, `apt-cache show <PACKAGE>`, or `dpkg-deb -I <DEB-FILE>` to show package control information. For more info see the [Multiarch Specification on Binary package control fields](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Binary_package_control_fields).

Comment: But how does the Linaro  64bit cross compiiler know there are two aarch64 dev packages on the 32 bit host machine?

Comment: When you say aarch64  can coexist with the 32bit aarch does that mean I have to unstall the original 32bit aarch package first then install the aarch64?  if the 32 bit aarch package is uninstalled can the aarch64 package be used for 32bit app too?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can get use -I (Include) for additional include path to resolve the header file error. but how does the cross compiler know the -lsensors??  i still got this cannot find -lsensors error. I did not set up the cross compiler at all. I only installed it to a directory (/opt) and my application uses g++ from that /opt directory to compile my code for cross compiling

Comment: I added more info on compiler and linker search paths.

Comment: my mistake. i actually have a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 Linux with Intel as the host PC and the target machine has a Ubuntu 16.04 Linux with ARM. Do I need to do the same multi arch thing above to let the ARM cross compiler recognize the -lsensor library in /usr/lib of the Intel 64bit host machine?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. All the above instructions refer to the build system (the system that is used to compile and link the executable file) since that is what you asked in the question.

Comment: for example, the 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 Linux host PC with Intel chip requires libsensors4-dev_amd64 while the 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 Linux target machine with ARM chip requires libsensors4-dev_amr64.  How does the AMR cross compiler in the host PC with Intel chip know there is an amr64 library for it, not the amd64 library????

Comment: So let me ask if there any way to extract the libsensor4_dev_64amr.dev to a directory without installing it so i can use gcc -L option to include that AMR library for my cross compiler?

Comment: ah.. looks like dpkg-dev -x can do the extraction.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to extract Deb packages without installation but I don't understand what you expect to gain from it. If you'd like to know how to do that please open a new question. After you install or extract the package you can use the `-L` linker flag to specify the library path if the linker doesn't find it. This is lined out in my answer. The linker will only select libraries for the host architecture (other's wouldn't work anyway). I'm not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: i got it solved. yes by dpkg-dev -x   extracting the amr dev into a directory and let the cross compiler to use -L solve the issue. i uploaded to target board and it ran perfectly. Thanks for the help.